# H1 NMR integrations

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I know this may be a bit of a dull question considering the integration on hydrogen NMR are usually quite precise but I was wondering If integrations in a linear depsipeptide compound could be thrown off by anything such as electron withdrawing inter or intramolecularly. The compound in question is a has a chemical formula of C77,H88,N4,O11,S4.curently the integration of all other protons are correct, however, the protons on two methyls on a valine, and the protons on a boc and tertbutyl group are off by a factor of three.

Comment: As deviation by a factor of three for *some* of the protons seems large (hence +1 for this question), does this observation persist even while 1) changing the pulse program during the NMR data acquisition (easier to do) as, for example, in Weizman, J. Educ. Chem. 2008, 85, 294 (DOI: 10.1021/ed085p294)?  Or/and 2) while changing the solvent used for NMR (may be trickier, may coil / decoil the peptide more or less than by now)?  3) Is there alternative analytical evidence one BOC / one tBu group  is present, and not three; like by LC-MS with a soft ionisation (CI, rather than EI 90 eV)?

Comment: There are lots of reasons why integrals may be out, even to a factor of 3. It would help if you posted the conditions of your acquisition; pulse program, pulse angle, number of scans, repetition delay, solvent, concentration. And by a factor of three - do you mean 3 times more or less than they should be?